# Assigned-Check for nested properties

Tags: delphi

Is it really necessary to cascade an assigned-check like this?

```
If Assigned(A) then
  If Assigned(A.B) then
    A.B.DoSomething;
```

Or should I be able to do

```
If Assigned(A.B) then
  A.B.DoSomething;
```

Should this work if A is NULL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two steps:

```
if Assigned(A) then
  if Assigned(A.B) then
    A.B.DoSomething;
```

If `A` is `nil`, even testing `Assigned(A.B)` will yield an access violation exception (close to 0).

But I would write this

```
if Assigned(A) and Assigned(A.B) then
  A.B.DoSomething;
```

Because of boolean short-circuit evaluation, `Assigned(A.B)` will not be evaluated if `Assigned(A)` is `False`.

Comment: TY, but the "if Assigned(A.B)" would also not be evaluated if the "if Assigned(A)" is False... I don't understand the reason for AND (except readability maybe)

Comment: Both versions are equivalent (thanks to boolean short-circuit evaluation, without which the compact version would fail with an access violation if `A` is `nil`). I just think the one-liner seems much more natural and neat and easy-to-read.

Comment: Not only do you save one level of indentation and indicate the semantic relation between the tests, it is more like natural language. Personally, I say "If you are hungry and you have food in your refrigerator, feel free to eat." rather than "If you are hungry: if you have food in your refrigerator, feel free to eat.".

Comment: Time for Delphi to support A?.B?.DoSomething();

Comment: Note that [Boolean Short-Circuit Evaluation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Boolean_short-circuit_evaluation_(Delphi_compiler_directive)) *can* be turned off, in which case `if Assigned(A) then if Assigned(A.B) then ...` is *technically safer* than `if Assigned(A) and Assigned(A.B) then ...`.  But most people don't turn off BSCE...

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko perhaps, but that is likely not going to happen until nullable types are implemented first, and Embarcadero has been pushing that off for years

Comment: @Remy Lebea - that list grows longer with every passing year: I've been waiting for async/await for eternity, but I guess IOS/Android/Linux are more important than native support for WinRT. Hard to justify Delphi for new projects.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Just curious; what is the point of turning off BSCE? I'm just curious in which scenario would it be useful

Comment: @Thorba This is for historical reasons. In standard Pascal, there is no BSCE.